# bootstrap panel with icons in the heading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap collapsible panel, I have 3 control icons icons in the heading that I want to use to call external functions, however clicking on any thing in the panel heading toggles the collapse function.

is there a way to isolate the icons at the end so they do not trigger the panel collapse?

I am using react.js and react-bootatrap.

```
var header = (
            <span>

                        {this.props.ticker.name}

                    <ButtonGroup bsSize="xsmall">
                        <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={<Popover id='Delete Stored Ticker'>Save stored ticker <strong>{this.props.ticker.name}</strong> from <strong>{this.props.ticker.area}</strong></Popover>} delayShow={500}>
                            <Button onClick={this._saveTicker}><Glyphicon glyph="floppy-disk"/></Button>
                        </OverlayTrigger>

                        <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={<Popover id='Delete Stored Ticker'>Save ticker as: <strong>{this.props.ticker.name}</strong> from <strong>{this.props.ticker.area}</strong></Popover>} delayShow={500}>
                            <Button><Glyphicon glyph="floppy-save"/></Button>
                        </OverlayTrigger>

                        <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={<Popover id='Delete Stored Ticker'>Delete stored ticker <strong>{this.props.ticker.name}</strong> from <strong>{this.props.ticker.area}</strong></Popover>} delayShow={500}>
                            <Button onClick={this._deleteTicker}><Glyphicon glyph="trash"/></Button>
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                    </ButtonGroup>
            </span>
        );

        return (
            <Panel id={this.props.ticker.id} collapsible header={header} className="storedTickerFiles">
                <ListGroup fill>
                    {items}
                </ListGroup>
            </Panel>
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Button `onClick` callback function, try this

```
_callback(e){ e.stopPropagation(); }
```